# Updating list view periodically

Tags: java, android, listview

I currently have a `List View` that takes data from an `ArrayList` that gets update every certain amount of time in the `MainActivity`. I want to update the List View every certain amount of time, let say 2 seconds. The problem is that I have this Adapter on a fragment and if I call the `notifyDataSetChanged();` from the Adapter, the View only gets update if I switch between the `MainActivity` and the `fragment`. I want that this List view refreshes every 2 seconds while I'm having the fragment in View. I have tried to run a `TimerTask` on the Adapter class, but I get an exception:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I guess you can only update the view from the MainActivity that has the fragment attached.

This how I was running the timer:

```
public void setTimer(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
}

public class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    //Refreshing list view
    public void run() {

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        timer.cancel();
        setTimer(2);
    }
}
```

Would it be safe to create an instance of the adapter on the MainActivity and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every certain amount of time?

Comment: post your full `stacktrace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Create one broadcast receiver in Fragment. with certain action name.
Lets say "refresh_data".
Then send this broadcast from MainActivity.
Example Code.

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
      private BroadcastReceiver  refreshData = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    };  
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(refreshData,
    new IntentFilter("refresh_Data"));  
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(refreshData);
       super.onPause();
    }
    }
```

In Activity call following method whenever your list is updated

```
Intent intent = new Intent("refresh_data");   
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I did create a LocalBroadCastManager and it worked great, but instead, I attached the register on the onResume() method and detached  it on the onPause() method. Not clear tho if its behaves as your suggestion of Overriding those tho methods.